# How to use javax.servlet.error.status_code in spring excetion handling

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-mvc, error-handling

am using below code to get status code in error controller

```
 Integer status_code = (Integer)
   request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.error.status_code");
```

and have custom error handler

```
public class TestNestableException extends Throwable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestNestableException.class);


    private int statusCode = 0;
    private String errorCode;
    private String message;


    public int getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }


    public void setStatusCode(int statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }


    public String getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }


    public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }


    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }


    public TestNestableException(final int statusCode, final String errorCode, final String errorMessage) {

        super(errorMessage);    
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
        this.message = errorMessage;

    }

}
```

have followed internet resources and implemented like above, but every time i am getting 500 status code

do i need add any extra code to set "javax.servlet.error.status_code"??

Can any one tell me where i am going wrong.. i have little knowledge in spring and servlets.